# Magento1.7 native captcha for NON-Loggen-In users

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I have used magento's native captcha for custom pages, as shown in [this link](http://mustakarhu.com/blog/magento-captcha-extension-ajax/). But it only displays if the user is not logged in. But i want to show magento's native captcha for logged in users also.
Is there any way to accomplish that ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you try manually adding the captcha into your template? Not through the layout method?

```
echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('captcha/captcha')
    ->setFormId('module_unique')
    ->setImgWidht(230)
    ->setImgHeight(50)
    ->toHtml();
```

As mentioned in that link, you will also need to load mage/captcha.js for it to work.

Comment: Yes Alvin i tried it, but same result. Captcha only display for non Logged-In users